# Asking about reading comprehension based on judgment of the book

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange website(s) do the following questions belong? (They don't pertain only to English.)

Suppose that a reader is considering what to read in order to learn more about a specific topic. Some books are (or are perceived as) easier to read than others. Some are harder.

1. What do authors do (or refrain from doing) to achieve that?
2. What makes readers judge that way?
3. Why do some readers comprehend a given book faster, and retain more, than others?

The only pertinent book that I found is [*How to Read a Book: The Classic Guide to Intelligent Reading*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Read-Book-Mortimer-Adler/dp/0671212095).

Comment: I think it must be [Writers.se]. That is more about the technical aspects of writing than specific works of literature. Though I'm not sure that such a question is narrow enough for any SE site. As you point out in your Meta-question here, entire books can be and have been written about this topic. Also I saw a downvote come in as I was typing this comment, but it wasn't me. I haven't voted on this question at all.

Comment: @KateGregory I will repeat if needed, but without repetition, how can I try to improve readability first?

Comment: It's probably several questions on writers. Readability can be at the sentence level, paragraph, chapter, book... and there are several different techniques to ask about or effects to try to achieve.